# Does $\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1 x dx$ equal zero?

Tags: calculus

Does $\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1 x dx$ equal zero? My contention is that it should, however several sources have said that it does not. I would think that the two areas on the left and the right of $x=0$ should be inverses and thus cancel, even if their areas are each infinite.

Comment: What sort of integral do you mean?

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is undefined

Comment: To get convergence to $0$ you'll have to consider the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: @ChrisEagle, I was unaware that there were multiple types of integral. Given that, I mean the first type of integral that one would learn in an AP BC Calculus class :)

Comment: You need to be careful here. What do you really mean by this integral? Your logic presupposes that you can "take a limit" of the sum of integrals just to each side of the singularity at 0. Do you have any theorems that tell you that this is a kosher way of integrating? Turns out its not. You are stumbling across something called a principal value so dont abandon your intuition just yet. But there is more going on here than meets the eye

Comment: The function as such is not riemann integrable as it is not bounded in $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is formalized by the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which deals with this exact type of problem.

However, note that it does not exist in the Riemann integral, because both the positive and negative part deal with $\infty$, and $\infty - \infty$ is undefined.

Comment: Why is $\infty - \infty$ undefined? Assuming that they're both, for example, $\aleph_1$, then they should be in one-to-one correspondence, right?

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x+c - x)= \lim_{x\to\infty} (x+c) - \lim_{x\to\infty} x = \infty - \infty$. But we know this limit is $c$, so $c = \infty - \infty$ for any choice of $c$. I can't speak strongly to the set theory part of your question (although perhaps someone else will chime in), but I would assume that one-to-one correspondence does not necessarily imply that the result is $0$. For example, consider the set of natural numbers and their squares, which have a one-to-one correspondence, but clearly there are not $0$ non-square numbers.

Answer (score 1):

They would cancel, but the integral doesn't exist, as 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x$$
doesn't exist. You need to calculate $\infty - \infty$ and that doesn't work. Regarding to the parametrisation you choose it won't be $0$.

Comment: Is there a way to parametrize it so that it would be zero?

Comment: Every symmetric partition (which i meant by parametrisation) yields $0$ as the value of the integral. But an integral only existis if the limit of of every partition is the same