# Finding the area of $\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know how to integrate basic equations, but I'm curious if it's possible to integrate something like:

$$\int^1_0\frac{1}{x}dx$$ since there's an asymptope.

Comment: Your text probably has a whole section on improper integrals.  Read that first.

Comment: The title and the body of the question ask somewhat different things.  The integral in the body is called an improper integral, because the limit of the integrand at one of the limits of integration is infinite or does not exist.  In some cases an improper integral may be evaluated by taking a one-side limit approaching a singularity, but in this case it turns out the integral cannot be evaluated that way.  Depending on the application the integral in the title might be treated more favorably, cancelling in some way the negative "area" to the left of the origin with positive area on the right.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable attempt to give meaning to $\int_0^1\frac1x\,dx$ will lead to the interpretation that there is infinite area there.

Here's how it goes: find $\int_t^1\frac1x\,dx$ for $t\in(0,1)$ and then take the limit as $t\to0^+$. You should be finding that you have $\lim\limits_{t\to0^+}\left(-\ln(t)\right)$.

And similarly, $\int_{-1}^1\frac1x\,dx$ can be interpreted as $-\infty+\infty$, which is very much undefined.

Comment: Why not mention the principal value?

Comment: @Peter It's not to my taste. I feel you need context to justify approaching the singularity from both sides at the same rate. Also it's not clear if OP's question is about $[-1,1]$ or $[0,1]$ or both.

Comment: It is an interesting matter in your last statement that mathematicians (at least generally) _do not_ consider the opposite-signed infinities to "cancel", that is, the integral is considered to diverge.  Some people who apply such integrals may disagree, feeling that since the "two sides" cancel as the asymptote is approached from both sides symmetrically, the integral ought to remain zero in the limit.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner If you approach the two sides of $0$ at different rates, you can end up with any finite or infinite interpretation for $\int_{-1}^1\frac1x\,dx$. Consider $\lim_{t\to0^{+}}\left(\int_{-1}^{-t}\frac1x\,dx$  $+\int_{t^2}^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx\right)=\lim_{t\to0}\left(\ln(t)-2\ln(t)\right)\neq0$.

Comment: That does seem sensible (and I had a look at Wiki on the Cauchy PV).  I've been interested in this question since I get asked about it by calculus students.  So the integral is considered "undefined due to indeterminacy".

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I answered a [similar question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332205/does-int-11-frac-1-x-dx-equal-zero/332208), which does mention the principal value as $0$.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams  Thanks for the referral.

Comment: I had trouble with the MathJax in my comment above. I meant $\lim_{t\to0^+} \big( \int_{-1}^{-t}\frac{1}{x}\,dx+\int_{t^2}^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx \big) =\lim_{t\to0^+}(\ln|t|-2\ln|t|)\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

You would "split" this around the asymptote as

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^-}\int_{-1}^t \ \frac{dx}{x} \ + \ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\int^1_t \ \frac{dx}{x} \ .  $$

In this particular case, neither integral converges, because the exponent of $ \ x \ $ in the denominator is 1 .  (Were the exponent between 0 and 1 , not inclusive, they would converge.  For example, $ \ \int_{-1}^1 \ \frac{dx}{x^{1/2}} \ $is finite.)

[Your title gives the limits of integration I am using here.  The body of your statement has only the integral "to the right of zero".]